# What would be the terminology for a state that has democracy but is also totalitarian?

Tags: terminology

Suppose, a country has democracy, i.e., people can properly vote and elect their leader.

However, because of some reason, like **populism** or inherent hate toward a minority group, the country consistently elects authoritarian leaders and hence the country morphed into a **virtual** fascist state.

I.e., the country is democratic by facade but fascist by behavior/action.

What would be the appropriate terminology for this country's situation?

Comment: "people can properly vote and elect their leader" Typically they can't under an autocracy. The opposition is disadvantaged first thing as a general rule I'd say. Can maybe examples be given for such democratic and fascist states?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution, India...

Comment: Democracy means that the population holds actual power over society. A totalitarian state can not have democracy. A fascist state with a democratic facade is just a fascist state. There's no need for additional terminology, because most totalitarian states pretend to be democratic and do in fact hold (meaningless) elections.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson Depends on the tradition that they were coming from. Like a failed demcoracy or some "communist" state, which has an ideology promoting democracy will at least pay lip service to the concept by pretending that this is some form of populism rather than a top down authoritarianism (whether that is true or not is a different question). But the classical fascists were conservatives (eurocentric definition) which actually believed in strong leadership and individual pettitions to a monarch/dictator rather than some form of legitimacy by the people and self-government.

Comment: @haxor789 I don't see how any of the things you wrote contradict what I wrote. Sure, sometimes totalitarian regimes don't bother with pretending to be democratic. But my point was that distinguishing between totalitarianism with voting and totalitarianism without voting is pointless.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson Not disagreeing just wanted to add that It's not a "don't bother" it's not even expected that they do (for people who actually believe in "just authority").. Also sure the difference is negligible and if you control every aspect of life, it's no longer a free decision anyway. Like there might not be an opposition party because they can't organize, they can't advocate for themselves, the media narratives are biased so that you can't really draw conclusions other than what you're supposed to and so on. So yeah the difference between them is pointless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Electoral Autocracy** is the term used to define democracies that have become increasingly authoritarian.

> Titled *Democracy Report 2022: Autocratisation Changing Nature*, the Swedish institute’s report notes that a new wave of democratisation is being seen in 15 countries while 32 countries reel under autocrasation. The countries are categorised based on V-Dem’s liberal democracy index (LDI), which captures both electoral and liberal aspects of democracy and goes from the lowest (0) to the highest (1) levels of democracy.
>
> The report highlights that autocratisation has “worsened” in India along with Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Cambodia, Hong Kong, Thailand and the Philippines in the Asia-Pacific region in the last decade.
>
> “Anti-pluralist parties are driving the autocratisation in at least six of the top autocratizers: Brazil, Hungary, India, Poland, Serbia, and Turkey,” the report notes.
>
> “Anti-pluralist parties and their leaders lack a commitment to the democratic process, disrespect fundamental minority rights, encourage demonization of political opponents, and accept political violence. These ruling parties tend to be nationalist-reactionary and have used government power to push forward autocratic agendas,” adds the report.

Sources:

1. [Democracy Report 2022: Autocratisation Changing Nature](https://v-dem.net/media/publications/dr_2022.pdf) (PDF)
2. ['India Among Top 10 Autocratising Nations; Democratic Slide to Continue': V-Dem Institute](https://thewire.in/rights/india-among-top-10-autocratising-nations-democratic-slide-to-continue-v-dem-institute)
3. ['Electoral autocracy': The downgrading of India's democracy](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-56393944)

Answer (score 0):

The situation I described can be characterized as an "***illiberal democracy***" or a "***hybrid regime.***" These terms are used to describe countries that possess certain democratic institutions, such as elections, but exhibit authoritarian tendencies or restrictions on civil liberties in practice.

In an illiberal democracy, the democratic processes may exist on the surface, but the government systematically undermines democratic principles and institutions, such as the rule of law, separation of powers, and protection of individual rights. This erosion of democratic norms often leads to the concentration of power in the hands of a single leader or ruling party, and the suppression of dissenting voices.

The term "hybrid regime" is another way to describe a country that combines elements of both democracy and authoritarianism. It acknowledges the presence of democratic features, but also recognizes the dominance of authoritarian practices and policies that undermine the true spirit of democracy.

In the specific case I mentioned, where a country consistently elects authoritarian leaders due to populism or hatred towards a minority group, one might also use the term "***electoral authoritarianism***." This term emphasizes the manipulation of democratic processes, such as elections, to maintain an authoritarian regime in power, often through the exploitation of populist sentiments or discriminatory ideologies.

Please note that the terminology used to describe political systems and situations can vary, and different scholars or analysts may use slightly different terms or classifications. Nonetheless, the terms "illiberal democracy," "hybrid regime," and "electoral authoritarianism" are commonly used to describe situations where democratic façades coexist with authoritarian practices.

Comment: *"rule of law, separation of powers, and protection of individual rights"* - these have never been claimed to be "democratic" rights or institutions, insofar as they limit democratic control. They are liberal rights. A democratic society may grant these rights to some extent, but they don't override democratic control. Your answer would make much more sense if you stuck to the concept of "illiberal democracy" which you yourself introduce, rather than conflating anti-democratic liberalism with democracy.

Comment: @Steve While separation of powers and a rule of law are things that mostly gain importance due to the absence of (direct) democracy as means to counteract the inherent authority of having leaders (even though they are elected), individual rights are somewhat ambiguous. Like sure if you overextend property rights to the point where they get into conflict with democracy you'd have a point, but some form of basic rights are necessary to have an equal participation necessary for any kind of democracy worth that name. Also mind you that "liberal" can be a very ambiguous term.

Comment: @haxor789, I think the point is that democracies grant rights to strengthen society, not to become irrevocably binding against change or revocation when they are found to be used to attack and undermine a democratic society. Foreign liberals are assaulting Orban because he has disciplined the judiciary in the name of democratic policy, and because he won't abide by the diktats of such liberals. The problem for them is not that Orban had insufficient democratic consent for this - their problem is that Hungarian democratic processes are being allowed to encroach on an unaccountable judiciary.

Comment: @Steve Democracies grant rights because the collective of citizens that makes up society thinks that is a good idea to do. Now ideally a democracy would be direct and consensus based and a society would split up when they no longer agree upon being a society and operating according to a certain mode of operation. In practice wealth is unequally distributed and members can't "simply leave" as much as assholes may ask for that and rather than a consensus based mandate the government rules by a majority rule. Which puts emphasize on the social contract which needs a higher form of justification.

Comment: @Steve 2/ That is idk consensus or a 2/3 majority or whatnot. It's not unalterable, but as it includes all of society it needs to have a more solid backing than a simple majority. Otherwise it's not a democracy but a majority oppressing a minority. And similarly rules made and enforced by the government should at least be applied justly and consistently, which is why the judiciary is not part of the government. If you are judge jury and executioner the chance of an appeal are rather slim. So based on these conditions the rule of law and the separations of power are integral to a "democracy"

Comment: @Steve 3/ There's also the other way around that a constitution was usually written before the birth of most people, so they didn't so much agree to it, but it was just already there. So technically there should be regular approaval or disapproval votes on that which rarely happen. Making persistence more likely (just in need of a minority) more likely than change (in need of a supermajority). Or stuff like in the U.S. where apperently judges can interpret laws making them an unelected government. That being said it's if it's a requirement to have a strong level of consent only that should do

Comment: @Steve 4/ Last but not least, Hungary is part of a supranational cooperation called the EU which has it's own constitution and agreed upon rules and as such it isn't so much "foreign liberals" but fellow members of that Union which argue that Hungary is a dictatorship and needs to change or quit and that they aren't going to support their autocracy. TL;DR no laws are unalterable in a democracy but you need a mandate for that and the more important that stronger the requirements for the mandate.

Comment: @haxor789, the EU *is* foreign liberals. As I say, I think it's reasonable Orban is being described as illiberal, but that's because Hungary's democracy is rejecting liberal diktats. He's not an autocrat - he's making the autocratic institutions like the judiciary *more* responsive to the Hungarian people.

Comment: @Steve Is he? Seems more like he's making them more responsive to himself which would make him an autocrat.

Comment: @haxor789, it would if *he* were an autocrat, but Orban actually stands for and wins elections (and I haven't heard anyone say these particular policies *don't* reflect the popular will). We seem to be in this doublespeak world - created by liberals of course - where elected politicians doing what people want is "undemocratic", and unelected judges (or EU officials) doing what the Hungarian people *don't* want is somehow a model of the "democratic". Hungary is rejecting liberalism through Orban, not rejecting democracy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148007/discussion-between-haxor789-and-steve).