# Electoral democracies in the OECD/EEA

Tags: western-world, authoritarianism

- [What would be the terminology for a state that has democracy but is also totalitarian?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/80306/what-would-be-the-terminology-for-a-state-that-has-democracy-but-is-also-totalit)

Can anyone give me an exhaustive list of current OECD/EEA countries behaving like electoral democracies/hybrid regimes/authoritarian states?

I know two of them:

1. Hungary
2. Poland

Can you add the rest?

**NOTE:** Turkey is not on the list as it has never been a proper democracy.

Comment: You are being a bit lazy here.  The countries in the oecd can be found on https://www.oecd.org/about/document/ratification-oecd-convention.htm and the ececonomist democracy index  is on Wikipedia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Economist_Democracy_Index  So cross referencing should be something you can do yourself.

Comment: @James K Your first link is not working.

Comment: It works for me

Comment: But even if it doesn't work for you, find a list of oecd members isn't something that takes very long

Comment: "Turkey is not on the list as it has never been a proper democracy." Which list? It´s defenetly on the list of oecd members.

Comment: This question is barely a complete grammatical sentence.

Answer (score 2):

By taking [list of oecd members](http://www.energybc.ca/cache/nuclear/nuclear2/www.oecd.org/document/1/0,2340,en_2649_201185_1889402_1_1_1_1,00.html) and [ELECTORAL DEMOCRACIES](https://www.mherrera.org/electoral.htm) geting something like this:

| COUNTRY | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| AUSTRALIA | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| AUSTRIA | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| BELGIUM | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| CANADA | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| CHILE | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| CZECH REPUBLIC | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| DENMARK | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| ESTONIA | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| FINLAND | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| FRANCE | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| GERMANY | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| GREECE | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| HUNGARY | PSEUDO DEMOCRACY |
| ICELAND | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| IRELAND | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| ISRAEL | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| ITALY | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| JAPAN | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| LUXEMBOURG | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| MEXICO | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| NETHERLANDS | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| NEW ZEALAND | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| NORWAY | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| POLAND | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| PORTUGAL | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| SLOVAKIA | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| SLOVENIA | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| SOUTH KOREA | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| SPAIN | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| SWEDEN | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| SWITZERLAND | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| TURKEY | PSEUDO DEMOCRACY |
| UNITED KINGDOM | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |
| UNITED STATES | ELECTORAL DEMOCRACY |

As can be seen from the coment by James K other sorces could give diferent defenitions for the coresponding countries.

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/80306/what-would-be-the-terminology-for-a-state-that-has-democracy-but-is-also-totalit